# SSH into a VM and run a command line and print the output - Python

Tags: python, bash, awk, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to SSH into my VM and run a command line and print the output

```
import paramiko
import time
import os
import sys

# Note
# sudo pip install --user paramiko


def ssh_con (ip, un, pw):
    global ssh
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print ("SSH CONNECTION ESTABLISHED TO %s" % ip)
    ssh.connect(ip, username=un, password=pw,key_filename='/Users/keys/id_ssc-portal', timeout=200)


def cmd(command):
    global ssh_cmd

    print ("Run : " + command)
    ssh_cmd.send("%s \n" %command)
    time.sleep(1)
    output = ssh_cmd.recv(10000).decode("utf-8")

    return output

ip = '172.19.242.27'
un = 'root'
pw = '####'

ssh_con(ip,un,pw)
ssh_cmd = ssh.invoke_shell()

p_id = cmd("ps -ef | grep vnc | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'")

print p_id <---------
```

I kept getting

```
/usr/bin/python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/restart_vnc.py
SSH CONNECTION ESTABLISHED TO 172.19.242.27
Run : ps -ef | grep vnc | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'
ps -ef | grep vnc | awk 'NR==1{print $2}' 


Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

But if I run it on the VM itself, I should see this

`[root@vm ~]# ps -ef | grep vnc | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'`

**25871** <--- my pid column should print out

How do I store a result of command in a variable and reuse that variable?

Ex. my pid. I want to grab it and kill it, and do something else more to it.

Comment: As an aside -- `ps -ef | grep vnc` can return the PID of `grep vnc`, since it contains the string `vnc`. Use `pgrep` instead to avoid this and other caveats, or, *much better*, use a proper process supervision system for managing services -- systemd, upstart, runit, DJB daemontools, etc.

Comment: Or, if you're inclined to go the quick-ugly-hack route anyhow, consider `ps -ef | awk '/vnc/ && ! /awk/ { print $2; }'` -- that way you're still only using one command-line element (`awk`, in this case), but having it do the work of filtering itself out.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Thanks for your advice, will do.

Comment: BTW -- does running `ssh root@172.19.242.27 $'ps -ef | grep vnc | awk \'NR==1{print $2}\''` work at an interactive bash prompt (other than the caveat around returning the PID of `grep` itself)? Before we try to automate things with paramiko, always best to be sure they function correctly in the first place. :)

Comment: Ohh ok. Nice tip. I didn't think of that.

Comment: It prompts me for a password.

Comment: Of course it does. So enter it. The point is that we want to see if the command is correct, not to be complete automation in and of itself.

Comment: After enter it, I seemed to get the pid spitting out.

Comment: (That said, if you *want* automation that doesn't rely on paramiko, consider `sshpass`).

Comment: Good! Then my answer should work.

Comment: To starters like me, do you recommend paramiko or sshpass for a couple commands lines automation like that ?

Comment: The big advantage of paramiko is that it lets you reuse a single [Transport](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport) for multiple commands without needing to play around with [ControlMaster/ControlSocket](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) (which is how the OpenSSH way of accessing that same protocol-level functionality works). If that advantage isn't important to you, it doesn't much matter.

Comment: Sorry I have to ask this question. Is `restart_vnc.py` the paramiko script you're talking about?

Comment: @whjm : yes. I have a couple more steps that I want to do after I get the pid. Ex. `kill -9 + pid` and so on ...

Comment: So `/usr/bin/python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/restart_vnc.py` is not what you were GETTING. Instead it's what you were RUNNING. Please update your question. It's quite confusing.

Comment: It the absolute path to my python, and my python file. what's wrong with that   ?

Comment: You said you kept getting `/usr/bin/python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/restart_vnc.py` so that made me think that's the output when you ssh to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invoke_shell()` is for **interactive** sessions. You don't need one here.

Use `exec_command(cmd)` instead, which is *exactly* equivalent in behavior to `ssh yourhost "$cmd"`.

Comment: How do I get store a result of command in a variable and reuse that variable ? Ex. my pid. I want to grab it and kill it, and do something else more to it.

Comment: `exec_command()` returns stdin, stdout and stderr -- so if you want to read stderr into a variable, easy 'nuff. Immediately close the stdin if you don't want to write anything to the command, and then read from stdout and stderr -- the former for your result, the latter for explanatory content to include in any exception if you have a failure.

Comment: (err, should have been "read stdout into a variable", above, since that's where your *result* will be).

Answer (score 1):

Complete answer using [`parallel-ssh`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parallel-ssh) library (it uses paramiko).

```
from pssh import ParallelSSHClient
ip = '172.19.242.27'
un = 'root'
pw = '####'

client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts=[ip], user=un, password=pw)
output = client.run_command("ps -ef | grep vnc | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'")
pid = list(output.stdout)
print pid
```

Benefits: Tons less boiler plate code, sane defaults, auto output strip and decode, parallel and asynchronous SSH client as extras.